# Display a unit on UIPickerView selection indicator?

Tags: iphone, uilabel, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView with 2 components allowing the user to select hours and minutes. I have seen many apps displaying a "hours" and "minutes" label on the selection indicator.

How do I do this.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that particular case, use `UIDatePicker` in `UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer` mode.

Comment: I can not use the UIDatePickerModeCountDownTimer mode for some reasons - is there any other way to easily set the SelectionIndicator's title?